# Reporting Services - concatenate string and parameter

Tags: postgresql, service, parameters, reporting, concatenation

What is the right query here?

I want to make "year" a parameter:

```
select distinct
p.id "pub_id"
from 
publication "p", organisation_association "oa", organisation "o", localized_string_text "lst_org"
where
p.id = oa.publication_id
and oa.organisation_id = o.id
and o.name_id = lst_org.localized_string_id
and p.submission_year = ?
and exists (select 1
        from
        publication "p2", organisation_association "oa2", organisation "o2"
        where
        p2.id = p.id
        and p2.id = oa2.publication_id
        and oa2.organisation_id = o2.id
        and o2.period_end_date < date ? + '-01-01')
```

However the concatenation at the last line produces a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parameter is passed as a year string:

```
and o2.period_end_date < date (? || '-01-01'))
```

If it is a date:

```
and o2.period_end_date < date_trunc('year', ?)
```

If it is a year number:

```
and o2.period_end_date < date (?::text || '-01-01'))
```

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo Neto!! It works perfectly! Again and again I am overwhelmeded by the power of these forums!!